# Thermal emission, after equilibrium, of two identical plates?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Take two identical plates at two different temperatures. Thermally isolate the "back" of the plates and connect the other sides via a "vacuum tunnel" with walls made of a perfectly reflecting material. One plate will emit A watts/m2 and the other B. Will the plates both emit (A+B)/2 after equilibrium has been reached? Assume that the heat capacity of the plates doesn't change in the temperature interval in question.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general. It depends on heat capacities of both plates.

If one plate (say, that with initial emission intensity A) has very much greater heat capacity, then the final temperature is close to its original temperature $T_A$, on both plates. The Stefan-Boltzmann law then says both plates radiate with intensity $A = \sigma T_A^4$ per unit area.

If both plates have equal heat capacity function $C(T)$, then the final temperature of both plates will be $\frac{T_A+T_B}{2}$. The Stefan-Boltzmann law then says each plate radiates with intensity $\sigma \frac{(T_A+T_B)^4}{16}$ per unit area.